# How to properly handle 403 errors with redirection in Ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework, error-handling, authorization

I'm trying to implement a global authorization error handler in Ionic using HttpInterceptor, which supposelly redirects to a HomePage in case a 403 is returned from the server:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { App } from "ionic-angular";

@Injectable()
export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    private navCtrl: NavController;

    constructor(private app:App) {
        this.navCtrl = app.getActiveNavs()[0];
    }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return next.handle(req)
            .catch((error, caught) => {
                if (error.status == 403) {
                    this.navCtrl.setRoot('HomePage');
                }
                return Observable.throw(error);
            }) as any;
    }
}
```

However, that navCtrl doesn't work properly (and also shouldn't not be used) inside the interceptor. 
On the other hand, adding the redirect logic in every service call is ridiculously hard to maintain:

```
someComponentMethod() {
    this.someService.findAll()
      .subscribe(response => {
          this.items = response;
      },
      error => {
        if (error.status == 403) {
          this.navCtrl.setRoot('HomePage');
        }
      });
  }
```

I think the main point of my question is "how to write a global redirection mechanism when a 403 is returned from the server". The code above is actually not working: the 403 error occurs, I can print stuff in the console through code inside the interceptor, but the 'HomePage' is not being loaded.

So how to properly handle 403 errors with redirection in Ionic?

Comment: Inside interceptor can you please print console.log(this). let me know they get undefined or getting anything

Comment: It's printing the object: ErrorInterceptor {... I think the main point of my question is how to handle the redirection, which is not working that way (the 403 error occurs, I can print stuff in the console through code inside the interceptor, but the 'HomePage' is not being loaded).